# grouping without additional packages

Tags: r, powerbi

I'm using R to plot my data, but am unable to install packages for the moment as my workplace has put up a lot of firewalls (currently trying to get IT to get them down).
In the meantime, I was wondering if by using the `plot()` function I was able to plot my data in groups.
I have three variables in my data: `IDName`, `Value`, and `Setpoints`.
I wanted to aggregate my values for each setpoint thus I used the `aggregate()` function although this will aggregate all data for each setpoint, whereby I only want it to aggregate depending on the `IDName`. All forms of grouping seem to require a package, thus I was wondering if anyone knew any workarounds.

I've supplied the code below (note that the R script is within PowerBI, but for the purposes of my question only R expertise is needed). It would also be great if you know how to colour these points accordingly to each `IDName`.

```
# dataset <- data.frame(IDName, Value, Setpoints)
# dataset <- unique(dataset)

# Paste or type your script code here:
dat <- aggregate(Value ~ Setpoints, dataset, mean)

x <- dat$Value
y <- dat$Setpoints
z <- dataset$IDName
plot(x,y, main ="Turbidity Frequency Distribution",xlab="% Time < Turbidity level", ylab="Turbidity (NTU)")
lines(spline(x,y))
```

Comment: Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including example data in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(dat)`.

Comment: do you mean that you want a single value computed per combination of values of `Setpoints` and `IDName` ?

Comment: Seems to flesh out the data the way I want when I change the aggregate function to the following: dat <- aggregate(Value ~ Setpoints + IDName, dataset, mean)
but I am still unsure how to colour the points by IDName and to get the lines(spline(x,y)) to do curves for each IDName rather than one averages line. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Unsure how to include example data as I'm running my script in powerbi where there is no output on the data side via dput(dataset)